# Implementing Firebase Messaging in Firemonkey

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firemonkey, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are a small team of Delphi developers who would love to implement Firebase Messaging in our Firemonkey app (Android and iOS).

We have successfully implemented both `GCM` and `APNS`, but we're looking forward to update our server and application to Firebase.

---

There is almost no reference on the web (since we're talking about `Firemonkey`).

- [This is the only thing](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi) I have found so far: an open source library that contains **no** information about **Messaging (Push Notifications)**.

---

Does anybody have a clue on how to implement Firebase Messaging at Firemonkey?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an implementation of GCM server-side / sending-APIs, all you need to do is to update the endpoint to point to:

> FCM endpoint: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Over time more feature will be added and you can implement them following the spec here:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: This is a good reference point, but I'm actually looking for information on the mobile-side; even though server-side will have to be implemented as well.

Comment: I've found some [reference here: https://github.com/master-webs , but I'm not sure how to apply it